# Unable to show the X-axis value only once inside the "rect " using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

     // **************************************************************************************** //

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Rectangle
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 90)
      .style("padding", "5px")
      .style("stroke", "#272525")
      .style("fill", "#272525")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0")
      .attr('x', 10)
      .attr('y', -45);

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Circle
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Text
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,13)")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "10pt");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      // **************************************************************************************** //

    .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
      var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
      d3.select(".mouse-line")
        .attr("d", function() {
          var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
          d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
          return d;
        });

      d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
        .attr("foo", function(d, i) {
          var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]);
          var bisect;
          var heights = [];

          var xDateValue = /\w*.\s.\d.\d*.\d*.:\d*.:\d*/.exec(xDate);
          // console.log(xDateValue);

          d3.selectAll('circle')
            .attr("transform", function(d, j) {
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
              idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

              var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

              while (true) {
                target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                pos = lines[j].getPointAtLength(target);
                if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
                }
                if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                else break; //position found
              }
              heights[j] = pos.y;
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
            });
          var avgheight = 0;
          for (var z = 0; z < heights.length; z++) {
            avgheight = avgheight + heights[z];
          }
          avgheight = avgheight / d.length;

          d3.select(this).selectAll('rect')
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + avgheight + ")";
            });
          var rectangleText = "";
          for (var t = 1; t < heights.length; t++) {
            rectangleText = rectangleText + "<br/>" + y.invert(heights[t]).toFixed(2);
          }

          d3.select(this)
            .selectAll('text').text(function(d, i) {
              return xDateValue + "  " + d.name + "  " + y.invert(heights[i]).toFixed(2)
            }).attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + (avgheight + 30 - (i * 25)) + ")";
            }).attr("dx", '20px');
          return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello, I am new to D3 library and trying to build a multiple line chart and show the data of X-Y axis inside a "rect" on mouse hover. I have struggled a lot and have achieved so far to show the data of X-Y axis on mouse hover inside the "rect". But the data of X-axis is getting displayed multiple times for multiple axis in this multi line graph. I want that the date value/ X-axis value should be displayed only once on top of other data rather than displaying multiple times. Please help me with any tips/ suggestions. Thanks for any help in advance. I know I am doing some silly mistakes but I am stuck.

Comment: Hello, please help me. I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick modification to your existing code.  It continues your approach and add an additional `text` element for the date:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

     // **************************************************************************************** //

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Rectangle
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 110)
      .style("padding", "5px")
      .style("stroke", "#272525")
      .style("fill", "#272525")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0")
      .attr('x', 10)
      .attr('y', -45);

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Circle
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("class","DateText");
    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Text
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "ValueText")
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,13)")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "10pt");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      // **************************************************************************************** //

    .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
      var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
      d3.select(".mouse-line")
        .attr("d", function() {
          var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
          d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
          return d;
        });

      d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
        .attr("foo", function(d, i) {
          var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]);
          var bisect;
          var heights = [];

          var xDateValue = /\w*.\s.\d.\d*.\d*.:\d*.:\d*/.exec(xDate);
          // console.log(xDateValue);

          d3.selectAll('circle')
            .attr("transform", function(d, j) {
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
              idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

              var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

              while (true) {
                target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                pos = lines[j].getPointAtLength(target);
                if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
                }
                if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                else break; //position found
              }
              heights[j] = pos.y;
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
            });
          var avgheight = 0;
          for (var z = 0; z < heights.length; z++) {
            avgheight = avgheight + heights[z];
          }
          avgheight = avgheight / d.length;

          d3.select(this).selectAll('rect')
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + avgheight + ")";
            });
          var rectangleText = "";
          for (var t = 1; t < heights.length; t++) {
            rectangleText = rectangleText + "<br/>" + y.invert(heights[t]).toFixed(2);
          }
  
          d3.select(this)
            .select(".DateText")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + (avgheight - 25) + ")";
            }).attr("dx", '20px')
            .text(xDateValue)
            .style("fill", "white");

          d3.select(this)
            .selectAll('.ValueText').text(function(d, i) {
              return d.name + "  " + y.invert(heights[i]).toFixed(2)
            }).attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + (avgheight + 50 - (i * 25)) + ")";
            }).attr("dx", '20px');
          return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh great ! thanks a lot Mark. You saved me. I went through your code and it was a bit of commonsense to append two text class and show different data in different text class. Learning a lot from stackoverflow. : )

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

     // **************************************************************************************** //

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Rectangle
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width / 2)
      .attr("height", height / 3)
      .style("padding", "5px")
      .style("stroke", "#272525")
      .style("fill", "#272525")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0")
      .attr('x', 10)
      .attr('y', -45);

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.innerRect')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("class", "innerRect");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Circle
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("class", "DateText");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line') // Text
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "ValueText")
      // .attr("transform", "translate(15,13)")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "10pt");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line innerRect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse hover show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line innerRect")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      // **************************************************************************************** //

    .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
      var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
      console.log(mouse);
      d3.select(".mouse-line")
        .attr("d", function() {
          var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
          d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
          return d;
        });

      d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
        .attr("foo", function(d, i) {
          var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]);
          var bisect;
          var heights = [];

          var xDateValue = /\w*.\s.\d.\d*.\d*.:\d*.:\d*/.exec(xDate);
          // console.log(xDateValue);

          d3.selectAll('circle')
            .attr("transform", function(d, j) {
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.date;
              }).right;
              idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

              var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

              while (true) {
                target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                pos = lines[j].getPointAtLength(target);
                if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
                }
                if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                else break; //position found
              }
              heights[j] = pos.y;
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
            });
          var avgheight = 0;
          for (var z = 0; z < heights.length; z++) {
            avgheight = avgheight + heights[z];
          }
          avgheight = avgheight / d.length;

          d3.select(this)
            .select('rect')
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + avgheight + ")";
            });

          var rectangleText = "";
          for (var t = 1; t < heights.length; t++) {
            rectangleText = rectangleText + "<br/>" + y.invert(heights[t]).toFixed(2);
          }

          d3.select(this)
            .selectAll('.innerRect')
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + (mouse[0] + 15) + "," + (avgheight + 40 - (i * 20)) + ")";
            })
            .attr('width', 10)
            .attr('height', 10)
            .attr("dx", '20px')
            .attr("dy", '0px')
            .style('fill', function(d) {
              return color(d.name);
            });

          d3.select(this)
            .select(".DateText")
            .text(xDateValue)
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + (avgheight - 25) + ")";
            })
            .attr("dx", '20px')
            .style("fill", "white")
            .style("font-weight", "bold")
            .style("font-size", "10pt");

          d3.select(this)
            .selectAll('.ValueText')
            .text(function(d, i) {
              return d.name + "  " + y.invert(heights[i]).toFixed(2)
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + (mouse[0] + 17) + "," + (avgheight + 50 - (i * 20)) + ")";
            })
            .attr("dx", '20px');

          return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the complete solution for the "mouseover" animation using D3 for this multi line chart. Thanks all for their help and support. Hope this helps.